# Play Integrity checks and reCAPTCHA failed: Missing valid app identifier meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

I am facing this issue even after doing the following steps:

- Adding SHA1 and SHA256 to the firebase.
- Starting the Play Integrity API.
- Adding the correct package name to the project in the firebase

I Was expecting the otp to be revived on my phone but it didn't.

so while checking the issue came to know that their is this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.